# How do I tell my git tools to NOT transform line endings?

Tags: git, github, newline

I'm using git across a number of platforms, and with containers, and am mounting filesystems between Windows and Linux containers. All the development tools I use can handle whatever line endings the source code has, silently, and sensibly. Except git.

I am finding git - commad line and desktop app - will transform line endings between Windows and Linux formats (CRLF ad LF). I don't want it to do that. I just want git to handle the files as supplied, and not try to second-guess how they are going to be used by transforming them. The transformed line endings is causing havoc. I create the files with LF line endings, and that is how I want them to stay, always, everywhere.

How can the git tools be told to leave the line endings alone? All documentation I have been able to find describe how to set various rules for different types of transforms for different tyoes of files within a specific repository. This is a function of my *tools*, not the repository. How do I set it for the *tools* to leave my file formatting well alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to add this into `.gitattributes`:

```
*    -text
```

That should do. That is to tell git: `I will take care of line endings`.

There's **important** information in the comments (not necessarily from me) so make sure to read them.

Comment: So that option for the repository says "do not normalise any file being checekd in". Presumably all developers with this repo checked out under Windows will need to discard their work files and clone again, othwerwise they may end up committing Windows line endings that they have checked out. I *must* make this change in a clone of the repo under a linux environment to ensure the files are "frozen" with Linux line endings? Is there no way I can set this for my *tools*, i.e. for *my* version of git on *my* machine? Or does is this always a property of the repository?

Comment: @Jason What you can write in `.gitattributes`, you can instead write into `.git/info/attributes` and it will affect only that clone of the repository.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't being clear. I was looking for the opposite - a global setting to say, "I will be handling the line endings". How other people handle line endings on that repo for their tools, will be their concern, so I'm not wanting to set it for the repo, but set it for *me on my machine*. Maybe that's just not how git works, and the repo gets the final say on how my tools work.

Comment: As @j6t salid, `.git/info/attributes` will work just as well and it won't be pushed/pulled.

Comment: I see, I need to set that in the repository I have cloned, and it won't get into the repository itself. Now, I would need to add this after the repo has been cloned (each time, for each repo), and after the line endings have been transformed already. I would then need to refresh all the working files from staging so I get the correctly (i.e. untouched) formatted versions? It still does not seem like a global setting that will define how source is checked out on the initial clone at least.

Comment: @Jason: make the initial clone with `-n` (short for the longer `--no-checkout`, which you can also use). Then edit the `.git/info/attributes` file as desired, and then run `git checkout`. If you forget, simply remove the entire work-tree and run `git checkout HEAD -- .` or `git reset --hard HEAD`, for instance.

Comment: In general, though, if (a) there is no `.gitattributes` and (b) you never set `core.autocrlf` to anything but `false`, Git shouldn't mess with line endings. It's when there *is* a `.gitattributes` that explicitly marks particular files as having particular endings, and/or something has set `core.autocrlf` to `true` or `input`, that Git starts messing about with line endings.

Comment: Note that there are personal and system-wide `.gitattributes` files. Your personal one is in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/attributes` or `$HOME/.config/git/attributes`. The system one is in `$(prefix)/etc/gitattributes`, where `$(prefix)` is a Git-compile-time option. The system and user files have lower precedence than any committed `.gitattributes`, though, so if someone has a committed `.gitattributes`, that will override your own user one. The `.git/info/attributes` file is the highest priority, fortunately.

Comment: Tonnes of information in these comments that complement this answer, all very much appreciated, and details that can be very hard to extract from the official documentation. Now, I would like to accept this answer, but expanded with these additional details that deal with the potential pitfalls of simply adding `* -text`. What's the best way to do that? @eftshift0 to do the honours with thanks? Looks like I could just accept it an edit it myself. Is that the correct etiquate?

Comment: How about that? ;-)

Comment: Go on then :-) I seem to have an edit button on your answer, so if I move some of those details up in coming days, will that be okay? Dunno - does the edit button mean I don't need to ask? I want to be very specific about my use-case and the reasoning, which so many tutorials and docs skip over and these commets cover nicely.

Comment: Feel free, man..... and I think it goes through approvals (I still don't know how that works).